# My function doesn't calculate a simple math operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a Temperature Calculator 
**Celsius and Farenheit**

I'm a completely begginer in Python

I have Python 3.3

So, I made this function to calculate a Farenheit value to a Celsius value

```
def C():
    print('Enter a temperature:')
    Fvalue = input()
    print(int(Fvalue) - int(32) * int((5/9)))
```

I run it and it just prints the Fvalue itself, it doesn't make the math operations

I hope you can help me guys

Comment: I fixed the indentation, assuming that was not the source of your problem.

Comment: You are doing integer arithmetic. This means that `int(5/9)` is `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your real problem lies here:

```
int(5/9)
```

`5/9` gives you `0.555` which when cast to `int()` gives you `0`

Try this:

```
print((int(Fvalue) - 32) * 5/9)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! in some minutes I give you accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you are casting the value of `5 / 9` to an `int`, which will give you 0 as a value. Just remove the cast, and it will be fine. And also you need to add parenthesis around the subtraction.

Change your print statement to:

```
print((int(Fvalue) - 32) * 5/9)
```

Comment: Or, just use a constant of `1.8`? :)

Comment: Yeah, I think it's the `int(5/9)` that's the problem.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Ok, so typecasting seems to be problem. Will update answer.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Except the OP then converts the result of division to an int.

Comment: @FredLarson With the suitably reversed op of course.... `(Fvalue - 32) / 1.8` or `CValue * 1.8 + 32` - saves the whole stupid 5 and 9 stuff...

Answer (score 0):

`int((5/9))` gives you 0, so `int(32) * int((5/9))` is 0, so you simply print `Fvalue`

This should fix your issue:

```
print((int(Fvalue) - 32) * 5.0 / 9))
```

With some easy math, this expression would be cleaner:

```
print (Fvalue - 32) / 1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code be should be as given below, u don't require casting for integers 32 and (5/9),

```
def C():
print('Enter a temperature:')
Fvalue = input()
print(int(Fvalue) - 32 * 5/9)
```